# TiledMap Properties Not Working In If Statement

Tags: java, slick2d, tiled

I am making a plat-former in Slick2D, and to handle the map I am using Tiled to make maps. There is one problem:
I have this code to check if a block should be added to an ArrayList of Rectangles to use as collision:

```
System.out.println(map.getTileProperty(map.getTileId(x,
                         y, 1), "blocked", "false"));
```

This returns "true" in the console for the x, y coordinates that have that property .
Yet, when I do this:

```
if (map.getTileProperty(map.getTileId(x, y, 1), "blocked", "false") == "true") {
 //Do Stuff
}
```

The if statement returns false. Does anyone know what to do to make the if statement return true for the tiles that have the blocked property?

Comment: @Mshnik Oh, ok. Thank you.

Comment: Note that in this case, you may want to use `Boolean.valueOf(String)` to convert the "true"/"false" string into a `boolean`.